# How to calculate value of FC layer in CNN

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Hi i am trying to understand how to calculate the values of each layers of CNN with stride but having hard time understanding the value of FC, FC3 and FC4.

[image]

Please let me know how we calculated Pool1 5x5x10 to make 400 and from 400 to 120 and 80.

Comment: (5x1)(2x2)(5x1)(2x2) = 400

Comment: You can read this https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-and-calculating-the-number-of-parameters-in-convolution-neural-networks-cnns-fc88790d530d